# Prevent Prettier from removing parentheses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using Prettier in VS Code on a React Native project and it removes parentheses in mixed operators or when declaring a var with a parenthesis. How to prevent Prettier from doing that?

Example 1:

```
 const foo = (a && b) || c;
```

After:

```
const foo = a && b || c;
```

Example 2:

```
const c = (a.toString()).toUpperCase();
```

After:

```
const c = a.toString().toUpperCase();
```

I know that in most cases it doesn't change the logic but I want to disable this feature.

Comment: This seems pretty fundamental... I don't want a code formatter to change my application logic... Any update on this?

Comment: I was looking into this same feature and found an open ticket on the issue but still seems to be no configuration option available yet
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/187

Comment: @BrysonKruk it should not "change the logic" there are some order rules in each programming language. **However I do agree this is a very bad behavior** and should not be allowed by default. There is also an opened issue around the same thing for ternary operators - https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3805

Answer (score 8):

You can use “prettier-ignore” comments to ignore parts of files.
Like // prettier-ignore

Here you have a link to documentation: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: This works, but I recommend to double check if you really need it. I had a case where I first thought prettier is changing the meaning of my expression by removing the brackets, so it would return something unintended. But then discovered that – of course – it didn't and I was the one that had an error in the expression. So it's good to assume that prettier is doing it right, and only use this to preserve purely visual deviations in the formatting, never logical ones. There might be exceptions, but then it would be good to file a bug report, I guess.

Answer (score -7):

You can config it in the settings.json and add "prettier.bracketSpacing", please read [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode)

You can also use eslint more customizable and can use different code style like airbnb ...

Comment: prettier.bracketSpacing is not what I need can you please re-check the examples above